# Send sensor data through GATT with Adafruit Bluefruit

Tags: arduino-ide, bluetooth, adafruit, ble

I have the BLE Module [Adafruit ItsyBitsy nRF52840 Express](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4481) and I want to send sensor values from a Hallsensor to my computer. I was able to have the right data checking with the Serial monitor.

```
int adcin = A1;
int adcvalue = 0;
float mv_per_lsb = 1200.0F/4096.0F; // 10-bit ADC with 3.6V input range
double freq = 100;
uint32_t lastMicros = 0;  //variable to track sampling frequency 
double microseconds = 1000000.0;
double interval = microseconds/freq;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Set the analog reference to 3.0V (default = 3.6V)
  analogReference(AR_INTERNAL_1_2);
  // Set the resolution to 12-bit (0..4095)
  analogReadResolution(12); // Can be 8, 10, 12 or 14
  // Let the ADC settle
  delay(1);
}

void loop() {

  // Get a fresh ADC value after intervall (1/freq)
  if (micros()-lastMicros >= interval)
  {
    adcvalue = analogRead(adcin);
    lastMicros = micros();
    
    // Display the results
    Serial.print(lastMicros);
    Serial.print(" [");
    Serial.print((float)adcvalue * mv_per_lsb);
    Serial.println(" mV]");
  } 
}
```

Then I tried to send these values through BLE connectin to my computer. So I knew I had to create a service and a characteristic for the GATT profile. But using the [guide from adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/bluefruit-nrf52-feather-learning-guide/blecharacteristic) was not really helpful. Right know I saw that with the following code I was able to see the module on my computer and read the characteristic I made. But it seems to just give me random Hex values rather than my sensor data.

```
#include <bluefruit.h>

BLEService        myService = BLEService(0x187A);
BLECharacteristic myChar = BLECharacteristic(0x184D);

BLEDis bledis;    // DIS (Device Information Service) helper class instance

int adcin = A1;
int adcvalue = 0;
float mv_per_lsb = 1200.0F/4096.0F; // 10-bit ADC with 3.6V input range
double freq = 100;
uint32_t lastMicros = 0;  //variable to track sampling frequency 
double microseconds = 1000000.0;
double interval = microseconds/freq;
float volt = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  //Setup for data acquisition
  // Set the analog reference to 3.0V (default = 3.6V)
  analogReference(AR_INTERNAL_1_2);
  // Set the resolution to 12-bit (0..4095)
  analogReadResolution(12); // Can be 8, 10, 12 or 14
  // Let the ADC settle
  delay(1);

  Serial.println("BLE data acquisition");
  Serial.println("-----------------------\n");

  // Initialise the Bluefruit module
  Serial.println("Initialise the Bluefruit nRF52 module");
  Bluefruit.begin();

  // Set the advertised device name (keep it short!)
  Serial.println("Setting Device Name to 'Adafruit_BLE'");
  Bluefruit.setName("Adafruit_BLE");

  // Set the connect/disconnect callback handlers
  Bluefruit.Periph.setConnectCallback(connect_callback);
  Bluefruit.Periph.setDisconnectCallback(disconnect_callback);

  // Configure and Start the Device Information Service
  Serial.println("Configuring the Device Information Service");
  bledis.setManufacturer("Adafruit Industries");
  bledis.setModel("Bluefruit");
  bledis.begin();

  // Setup the BLEService and BLECharacteristic classes
  Serial.println("Configuring the custom Service");
  setupSer();

  // Setup the advertising packet(s)
  Serial.println("Setting up the advertising payload(s)");
  startAdv();

  Serial.println("Ready");
  Serial.println("\nAdvertising");
}

void startAdv(void)
{
  // Advertising packet
  Bluefruit.Advertising.addFlags(BLE_GAP_ADV_FLAGS_LE_ONLY_GENERAL_DISC_MODE);
  Bluefruit.Advertising.addTxPower();

  // Include custom Service UUID
  Bluefruit.Advertising.addService(myService);

  // Include Name
  Bluefruit.Advertising.addName();

  Bluefruit.Advertising.restartOnDisconnect(true);
  Bluefruit.Advertising.setInterval(32, 244);    // in unit of 0.625 ms
  Bluefruit.Advertising.setFastTimeout(30);      // number of seconds in fast mode
  Bluefruit.Advertising.start(0);                // 0 = Don't stop advertising after n seconds  
}

void setupSer(void)
{
  myService.begin();
  
  myChar.setProperties(CHR_PROPS_READ);
  myChar.setPermission(SECMODE_OPEN, SECMODE_OPEN);
  myChar.setFixedLen(4);
  myChar.begin();
}

void connect_callback(uint16_t conn_handle)
{
  // Get the reference to current connection
  BLEConnection* connection = Bluefruit.Connection(conn_handle);

  char central_name[32] = { 0 };
  connection->getPeerName(central_name, sizeof(central_name));

  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(central_name);
}


void disconnect_callback(uint16_t conn_handle, uint8_t reason)
{
  (void) conn_handle;
  (void) reason;

  Serial.print("Disconnected, reason = 0x"); Serial.println(reason, HEX);
  Serial.println("Advertising!");
}


void loop()
{
  // Get a fresh ADC value after intervall (1/freq)
  if (micros()-lastMicros >= interval)
  {
    adcvalue = analogRead(adcin);
    lastMicros = micros();
    volt = (float)adcvalue * mv_per_lsb;
    // Display the results
    Serial.print(adcvalue);
    Serial.print(" [");
    Serial.print(volt);
    Serial.println(" mV]");
    myChar.write16(volt);
  } 
}
```

I really got confusing with how to write my sensor values to the characteristic.

Does anyone know how I can achieve that?
Cheers